# Reincarnation as animals

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, animals, chasidut-hasidism, arizal, reincarnation

One of the doctrines of Lurianic Kabbalah is the notion of reincarnation. My question is if it is possible to reincarnate as an animal when you die as a human?

Comment: I've been taught that Tzadikim reincarnate as fish

Comment: Reincarnation is discussed extensively in Zohar, so it's not unique to the Arizal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Gate of Reincarnation Chapter 22, Rabbi Vital passes on from the Arizal that indeed it is possible to be reincarnated into inanimate objects, plants and animals, depending on the correction needed.

Comment: Is a stone better than an animal. Or the opposite?

Comment: Stone is worse according to Minshnat Gilgulim, as the anguish of having fallen so far is much worse, and other reasons. I imagine it is even less comfortable than an animal too @Shababnik

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikb0WgLDVqE full discussion